# Saving a file inside the application's memory

Tags: php, android

I am trying to download a file from a php get url that has username and password. My code doesn't show any errors and the progress bar shows me that the file is downloaded but when I try to print the list inside the Log I cannot see the file. What am I doing wrong?

That's the code inside the `doInBackground` section in the `AsyncTask` which I have called inside the `onCreate` and have put the url inside the parameters.

```
protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
            InputStream input = null;
            OutputStream output = null;
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            try{
                URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
                input = connection.getInputStream();
                output = new FileOutputStream(context.getFilesDir()+"video.m3u");
                byte data[] = new byte[4096];
                long total = 0;
                int count;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1){
                    total = total + count;
                    if (fileLength > 0){
                        publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                    }
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                return e.toString();
            }finally {
                try{
                    if (output != null){
                        output.close();
                    }
                    if (input != null){
                        input.close();
                    }
                }catch (IOException ignored){
                }
                if (connection != null){
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
            }
            return "";
        }
```

In the `onPostExecute` section I have written this code

```
if (result.equals("")){
   String path = context.getFilesDir().toString();
   Log.d("Files", "Path: "+ path);
   File directory = new File(path);
   File[] files = directory.listFiles();
   Log.d("Files", "Size: " + files.length);
   for (int i = 0; i<files.length; i++){
        Log.d("Files", "File Name: " + files[i].getName());
   }
}
```

But the only thing that I get printed is this:

```
D/Files: Path: /data/data/my.app.package/files
D/Files: Size: 1
D/Files: File Name: instant-run
```

I can't see the file that has been downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is this line

```
  output = new FileOutputStream(context.getFilesDir()+"video.m3u");
```

context.getFilesDir() doesn't return String, it's File object you need to do this

```
  output = new FileOutputStream(context.getFilesDir()..getAbsolutePath()+"/video.m3u");
```

Comment: can I ask you a question? How can I play this file in an external player in Android? do you know any good link??

Comment: what do you mean ? play video.m3u outside your app? but execute from your app?

Comment: save it from my app in the internal storage of the phone and open it with an external player because I have heard that Android internal player cannot play m3u

Answer (score 0):

The file path you are saving to is wrong. Right now you are saving to
`output = new FileOutputStream(context.getFilesDir()+"video.m3u");`

it needs to be `output = new FileOutputStream(context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/video.m3u");`

Hopes this helps.